# onchange event doesn't invoke inside <apex:repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist

My onchange event is not firing if it is inside the `<apex:repeat` and if I remove the repeat the onselect is invoking and working fine, what might be the issue? I do not find any log so it means that its not even firing the action method.

VFP:

```
    <apex:repeat value="{!events}" var="itr">    
     <apex:selectList id="rt" label="Job Types" value="{!typeId}" size="1">
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="new" action="{!onChangeSelect}"
     />
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!selecttypes}"/></apex:selectList>
   </apex:repeat>
```

APEX:

```
public PageReference onChangeSelect() 
{
   system.debug(':::onChangeSelect'); 
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Where is <apex:repeat tag? I don't see it. Please add more code details.

Comment: oops updated my question

Comment: Your code looks good. If you can share your controller and VF page might give us more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an `<apex:actionRegion>` before the `<apex:selectList>` element.

Comment: 1+ I did not realized that causing the issue on my page

Answer (score 0):

This controller:

```
public class MyController {

    public Integer[] getItems() {
        return new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
    }

    public String selected {get; set;}

    public SelectOption[] getOptions() {
        return new SelectOption[] {
                new SelectOption('a', 'a'),
                new SelectOption('b', 'b')
                };
    }

    public PageReference onChange() {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
                ApexPages.Severity.INFO,
                'onChangeSelect ' + DateTime.now()
                ));
        return null;
    }
}
```

and page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
<apex:form>
<apex:outputPanel id="panel">
    <apex:pageMessages/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!items}" var="item">    
        <apex:selectList value="{!selected}" size="1">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="panel" action="{!onChange}"/>
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
   </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

demonstrate that `apex:actionSupport` "onchange" does work inside an `apex:repeat`.

(For this sort of code to make sense, the `apex:selectList`s need to be bound to separate properties not the same property.)

Comment: my page is a bit complex and its hard to post the entire page here.

Comment: @NickKahn Yes well done for not posting the whole thing... Given that the simple apex:repeat case I tried works its likely to be something else in your page; I suggest your remove various pieces to try to identify what. I find the adding a message approach more convenient than looking in the debug log and it is one less thing that could go wrong.

Comment: @NickKahn See you just accepted the action region answer; if you have any insight why it works others might benefit from an explanation.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not have any insight except what I read here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm